# Como converter código HTML para um arquivo PDF em java?

Tags: java, html, arquivo, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde preciso converter um código HTML, que esta salvo no banco, em um arquivo .PDF. Não há necessidade de salvar este arquivo no servidor.

Eu nunca fiz algo semelhante. Como fazer isso usando Java?

Comment: Coloque um trecho de código do que você já fez! Você está usando java web?

Answer (score 1):

Faço exatamente isso em uma aplicação desenvolvida com o framework Grails. Utilizo um plugin chamado Rendering que, por sua vez, utiliza uma biblioteca Java chamada [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/). Eu poderia postar um Exemplo em Grails, mas creio que não ia te ajudar muito, já que você está trabalhando com Java.

O Flying Saucer utiliza uma biblioteca chamada iText. Esta é a biblioteca que efetivamente tranforma um XHTML em um PDF. Existem algumas questões de licenciamento que precisam ser verificadas.

Uma resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633780/converting-html-files-to-pdf) onde é recomendado a mesma coisa.